# why does login page appear when I am already logging in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have recently published my first programmed web application, before that my web application was working fine on a local server which is working on a local network. In the application, the user has to login first in order to be able to open and browse the pages. Now when the user login the pages open fine but after a moment when the user opens a page, the login page appears asking to login. this action keeps happening many times.

my login code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return View(model);
       }

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, 
shouldLockout: false);
     switch (result)
     {
         case SignInStatus.Success:
              return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
         case SignInStatus.LockedOut:                        
              return View("Lockout");
         case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
              return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = 
              model.RememberMe });
         case SignInStatus.Failure:
              default:
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName or Password is not correct");
              return View(model);
    }
}
```

In web.config file I wrote:

```
<system.web> 
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <sessionState timeout="30" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
 </system.web>
```

Comment: how frequent this happen? is there an event or an specific action the user do in order to get logged out?

Comment: it actually happens many times, sometimes each time I open a new page or action, and sometimes the app works fine without this problem. and it does not happen because of any specific action.

Comment: What is the nature of this website? is it accessing files or creating files/folders on the server?

Comment: it is accessing files and write/read for all users

Comment: does it create folders in the same folder of the website?